# matlab Is there something like list comprehension as it is in python?

Tags: arrays, matlab

I am looking for something like list comprehensions in matlab however I couldnt find anything like this in the documentary.

In python it would be something like

```
A=[i/50 for i in range(50)]
```

Comment: You might find http://www.scipy.org/NumPy_for_Matlab_Users useful. Note that in Numpy, I'd probably do `A = np.arange(50)/50.0` instead of a list comprehension for speed.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Matlab is very fond of 'vectorizing'. You would write your example as:

```
A = (0:49) ./ 50
```

Matlab hates loops and therefore list comprehension. That said, take a look at the [`arrayfun`](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/arrayfun.html) function.

Comment: MATLAB *hates* loops? Don't think so. It just provides you with other ways of doing things .. As a result, *you* eventually end up hating them.

Comment: I end up hating to write loops in MATLAB, not loops in general. Me and my MATLAB have been through a lot... if software could have any empathy it would now hate loops too.

Comment: It may be worth pointing out that this is an area where matlab and python are similar. Python also is slow at looping (when compared to compiled languages like C), and you should try to vectorize wherever possible in python if computation time is important, typically using numpy.

Answer (score 6):

You can do:

```
(1:50)/50
```

Or for something more general, you can do:

```
f=@(x) (x/50);
arrayfun(f,1:50)
```

Answer (score 2):

No, Matlab does not have list comprehensions. You really don't need it, as the focus should be on array-level computations:

```
A = (1:50) / 50
```

Answer (score 0):

Matlab can work with arrays directly, making list comprehension less useful

Answer (score 0):

If what you're trying to do is as trivial as the sample, you could simply do a scalar divide:

```
A = (0:50) ./ 50
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to generate a list in Matlab that goes from 0 to 49/50 in increments of 1/50

```
A = (0:49)/50

B = 0:1/50:49/50

C = linspace(0,49/50,50)
```

**EDIT** As Sam Roberts pointed out in the comments, even though all of these lists should be equivalent, the numerical results are different due to floating-point errors. For example:

```
max(abs(A-B))
ans =
   1.1102e-16
```

Comment: None of these values of A are the same! Try calling them A, B and C and comparing them with all(A==B) etc. An interesting exercise in the different behaviour of colon, double colon and linspace. I know zero about Python, but if someone on this thread were able to compare these three MATLAB options with the Python list comprehension it might be useful. EDIT: removed my -1, I didn't mean  to sound critical, it was a good answer.

Comment: @SamRoberts: That's a very good point. Even though theoretically, all solutions should be equivalent, their results are not identical due to floating point errors.

Comment: Just so that people understand my previous comment - @Jonas originally called all his variables A, B, and C just A. Following his edit, his answer is now clearer, but my comment makes less sense...

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work help with your numerical example but for the special case of strings there is the [compose](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/compose.html) function that does the same thing as a list comprehension of the form:

```python
s = [f"Label_{i}" for i in range(1, 6)]
```

Example:

```matlab
str = compose("Label_%d", 1:5)
```

Result:

```
str = 

  1×5 string array

    "Label_1"    "Label_2"    "Label_3"    "Label_4"    "Label_5"
```