# Matlab shorthand for `for` with nested `if` (like Python's list comprehension)

Tags: matlab, for-loop, inline, list-comprehension

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8327013/matlab-is-there-something-like-list-comprehension-as-it-is-in-python) somehow addresses the problem, but not from the side I'm looking for.

I'd like to map an array into another, picking only the elements below a certain threshold. Basically a `for` loop, with an `if` conditional statement which checks the threshold.

I'm aware of the `arrayfun` function, but I don't know a way to put the conditional statement in it without defining a new function.

Is there a way to perform this task with an inline instruction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this is what you are looking for:

```
 A = (0:49) ./ 50; % Generate the initial array.
 B = A( A < 0.5 ); % Map an array into another, picking only the elements below a certain threshold.
```

Comment: Or: A(arrayfun(@(x) x < 0.5, A)), I think this can be extended more easily to matrices.

Comment: Yep arrayfun + anonymous function. More general.

Comment: Thank you! Now I have to understand the anonymous function...and where can I find the guide for the mapping operators?

Comment: An "anonymous function" is just a regular function (with some constraints.) Don't let the funny syntax scare you off - they can be used in very powerful ways.

Comment: I do not know what you mean by mapping operators. Anonymous functions are really simple: `x = @(y,z) y + z` consists of 3 parts. `x` is the function name, `@(y,z)` means that the function expects 2 arguments, namely `y` and `z`. The result is `y + z` in this case. So in this case you could now call it using `x(3,5)` and it would return the value `8`. [edit] You can ofcourse also use this notation as a parameter. So for `arrayfun()` you just specify the argument and the computation, e.g. `arrayfun(@(y,z) y+z, ..)`. Does this answer your question?

Comment: Documentation on Anonymous Functions in MATLAB: http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f4-70115.html

Comment: Mapping operators are any operator that produces a Boolean expression.

Comment: Why not simply `B = A(A<0.5)` -- no need to flatten `A`.

Comment: Good point, thanks. Corrected. Though same performance it seems: `clear all; tic; A = (0:300000000); B =  A(A(:)<50000); toc
clear all; tic; A = (0:300000000); B =  A(A<50000); toc`
Elapsed time is 2.370389 seconds. Elapsed time is 2.385871 seconds.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt yes, I was meaning that I have to read the manual :)

Comment: @Yuri I didn't know that you can index a matrix with bitmaps; it's a very flexible syntax